# haskell mocking: define func in datatype with class-constraint

Tags: haskell

there is the function

```
httpLBS :: MonadIO m => Request -> m (Response ByteString)
```

in the **Network.HTTP.Simple** module ([doc](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/http-conduit-2.2.3/docs/Network-HTTP-Simple.html)), which i want to pass around (for mocking later in integration-testing) with my **Ctx** data-object

```
data Ctx =
    Ctx {
        token :: String,
        httpLBSFunc :: MonadIO m => Request -> m (Response ByteString)
    } deriving (Show)
```

but I'm getting this error:

```
Prelude> :l Context.hs
[1 of 1] Compiling Context          ( Context.hs, interpreted )

Context.hs:19:32: error: Not in scope: type variable ‘m’
   |
19 |         httpLBSFunc :: MonadIO m => Request -> m (Response B.ByteString)
   |                                ^

Context.hs:19:48: error: Not in scope: type variable ‘m’
   |
19 |         httpLBSFunc :: MonadIO m => Request -> m (Response B.ByteString)
   |                                                ^
Failed, no modules loaded.
```

how is it possible to define this method in my **Ctx** data-type correctly??

Comment: Ctx need parameter like: data Ctx m = Ctx {...}

Comment: ok, so you mean:

    data Ctx m =
        Ctx {
            token :: String,
            httpLBSFunc :: m
        }

? but then i have to specify the Ctx type everywhere with "Ctx MonadIO (Response ByteString)" ... right? i wouldn't like that. can't i put that "MonadIO (Response ByteString)" constraint somewhere inside the type?

Comment: If you want put the constraint in Constructor, considers to use GADTs instead. Or, put constraint on data type like: data MonadIO m => Ctx m = {...} with enable -XDatatypeContexts language extension,it has been deprecated, but you can still use it.

Answer (score 0):

i don't what the drawbacks are by replacing the constraint **MonadIO** with the actual Monad **IO** but for me it was sufficient to get it running:

```
data Ctx =
    Ctx {
        token :: String,
        httpLBSFunc :: Request -> IO (Response ByteString)
    } deriving (Show)
```

i dont even get the exact difference between them